# Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred Swift closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures, swift3

I'm trying to return an array of Strings in a Swift 3 closure. I'm getting the error `Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred` when I try to return the array. Here's the relevant code:

Define function closure:

```
var userArray: [String] = []
func getUsers(_ userID: String, closure:(([String]) -> Void)?) -> Void{
  userArray.append(user as String)
  closure!(userArray)
  }
}
```

Return the array:

```
_ = self.getUsers(userID!, closure: { (userArray) in //Generic parameter error...
        self.users.append(userArray)
    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `userArray`, `user`, and `users`?

Comment: `var userArray: [String] = []`, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry about that. I left out code so it didn't overwhelm people. userArray is an array of Strings. user is a String, and self.users is also an array of Strings.

Comment: Well, this *isn't even close* to compiling.  For example, `var userArray : String = []` is trying to assign an `Array` into something, mistakenly, defined as a `String`.  Additionally in `user as String` the value `user` isn't defined in the shown scope.

Comment: Besides that, you are passing an `Optional` closure and then just 'banging' it, with `!`?!  At least use `closure?(userArray)`.

Comment: Again I apologize. I might have left out too much code. Ended up confusing everyone instead of helping. I updated the array code. There's a lot of Firebase going on in the code so I tried to leave that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple coding errors.  The following compiles (even if it may or may not meet your code's intent).

```
  1> var userArray: [String] = [] 
  2. func getUsers(_ user: String, closure:(([String]) -> Void)?) -> Void { 
  3.   userArray.append(user)
  4.   closure?(userArray) 
  5. } 
userArray: [String] = 0 values

 11> var users : [String] = [] 
 12. getUsers("me", closure: { (userArray : [String]) in 
 13.         users += userArray
 14.     }) 
users: [String] = 1 value {
  [0] = "me"
}
```

Comment: the `userArray: [String]` is what fixed it! Adding the data type seemed to do the trick. Thanks!